# Development and production configurations for Rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

For deliverability reasons, I installed SPF records and other types of authentication to make sure production emails aren't flagged as spam. The side-effect is that when I run tests from my localhost they don't work. Is there a "Rails Way" to have development vs. production credentials for a mailer? It seems like I could build my own logic based on the `Rails.env` variable, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is already support for this.

Comment: Have you tried putting different configuration in `config/environments/development.rb` vs `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: Have you considered using [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher)?

Comment: @davogones I have not. But that's exactly the kind of thing I'd like to do. But the docs only talk about adding `delivery_method_options` inside the mailer class. If you know another way I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @muistooshort That looks like a cool tool. I skimmed through the intro  but it wasn't obvious how it helps besides not requiring mail to travel through actual smtp servers. Seems like you still have to trigger emails manually and then inspect them in the client. What am I missing?

Comment: It acts as its own mail server (more or less) so you just configure the appropriate hostname and port in your non-production email configuration and email doesn't go outside the local environment.

Comment: Are you trying to change the global action mailer configuration for all mailers, or only for specific mailers?

Comment: @davogones I only have one mailer at the moment so Im not sure it matters.

Answer (score 0):

The "Rails way" is to put shared configuration in `config/application.rb` and environment-specific overrides in `config/environments/<env>.rb`.

In your case I would put your SPF stuff in `config/environments/production.rb`.

See this link for more information on configuring ActionMailer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

Comment: That makes complete sense for environment stuff but the configurations for mailers go in the individual mailers according to the docs. Right?

Comment: Which configuration are you referring to? The bulk of ActionMailer configuration goes into the Rails config.